# Como puedo darle tamaño a una etiqueta label?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3, asp.net-mvc

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un label dentro de un div que tiene un tamaño especifico, pero el texto del label sobrepasa el tamaño del div y quisiera que si el texto no cabe en el div lo muestre debajo en otra linea.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<div style="z-index:0; position: absolute; top: 2487px;  left: 8px;   
height: 45px; width: 353px;">
<label disabled="disabled" control-type="TIssLabel" id="7662"   
name="IssLabel29" style=" font-weight: bold;">Do you experience any
psychological stress and or medical problems while at work?
</label>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Según el ejemplo dado funciona correctamente. le puse colores para que lo veas como el label se parte en dos lineas. si no lo ves igual en tu implementación prueba a ponerle `display:inline;` al style del label

```html
<div style="z-index:0; position: absolute; top: 0;  left: 8px;   
height: 45px; width: 353px;border:1px dashed red;">
<label disabled="disabled" control-type="TIssLabel" id="7662"   
name="IssLabel29" style=" font-weight: bold;background-color:#fe0;">Do you experience any
psychological stress and or medical problems while at work?
</label>
<div>
```

Comment: haa pues si no se porque en mi codigo me sale todo corrido alguna clase css sera, revizare, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: si puede que alguna regla CSS le cambie el inline (el flow natural de un label) por display:block o algo así